# Loop nested array values using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

Using the following JSON below, how do I loop the inner Errors and Messages values using jQuery:

JSON Format:

```
{
   "PagesCreated":0,
   "AssetsCreated":0,
   "AssetsUpdated":0,
   "Messages":[
      "Test message!",
      "Test message!",
      "Test message!"
   ],
   "Errors":[
      "Test error!",
      "Test error!",
      "Test error!"
   ],
   "EllapsedTime":"00:00:00.0000382"
}
```

Current jQuery in place on ajax success call:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "PagesCreated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "AssetsCreated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "AssetsUpdated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "EllapsedTime") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "Messages") {
        // TODO - How do I loop inner Messages values here?
    }
    else if (key == "Errors") {
        // TODO - How do I loop inner Errors values here?
    }
});
```

If it helps this is the c# object I am serializing to json:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int PagesCreated { get; set; }
    public int AssetsCreated { get; set; }
    public int AssetsUpdated { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EllapsedTime { get; set; }
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .each method again:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "PagesCreated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "AssetsCreated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "AssetsUpdated") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "EllapsedTime") {
        console.log(value); // works
    }
    else if (key == "Messages") {
        $.each(value, function (innerKey, innerValue) {
           console.log(innerValue);
       }
    }
    else if (key == "Errors") {
        $.each(value, function (innerKey, innerValue) {
           console.log(innerValue);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I originally tried something similar, but was only  doing:   $.each(value) { }});

Comment: FYI, your example is missing closing tag just in case somebody runs into issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use jQuery to loop arrays. Plain JS works well and can be reused in all frameworks

You can test the type and react accordingly

```js
const data = { "PagesCreated": 0, "AssetsCreated": 0, "AssetsUpdated": 0, "Messages": [ "Test message!", "Test message!", "Test message!" ], "Errors": [ "Test error!", "Test error!", "Test error!" ], "ElapsedTime": "00:00:00.0000382" };

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (typeof value == "object") {
    console.log(key, value.join(", "))
  } else console.log(key, value)
});
```

jQuery version - only difference is `$.each(data,(key, value) => {`

```js
const data = { "PagesCreated": 0, "AssetsCreated": 0, "AssetsUpdated": 0, "Messages": [ "Test message!", "Test message!", "Test message!" ], "Errors": [ "Test error!", "Test error!", "Test error!" ], "ElapsedTime": "00:00:00.0000382" }

$.each(data,(key, value) => { 
  if (typeof value == "object") {
    console.log(key, value.join(", "))
  } else console.log(key, value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example using plain js. Alternatives are always good. However, the question was specific to jQuery so accepted the other answer as it was more relevant.

Comment: I added a jQuery version. I just had to change to `$.each(data,(key, value) => { `